# Position handle where it has been clicked on the trackbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, nouislider

I'm using the excellent noUiSlider (https://refreshless.com/nouislider/) for a project. I need to set it up so that when first viewing the slider it will not include the handle at all, when clicking the trackbar the handle appears in the position that has been clicked.

The showing of the hidden handle works, but how can I make it so the appearing handle is positioned at the same position as where the user has clicked? Right now the handle appears and comes sliding from the starting position. So I need the start position to be the same as where the user has clicked.
This is my JS so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider-vas-vertical-2');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
start: [0],
orientation: 'vertical',
direction: 'rtl',
range: {
  'min': [0],
  'max': [100]
},
pips: {
  mode: 'values',
  values: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
  density: 0
}
  });

  $('.vas-slider .noUi-base').on('click', handleSliderClick);

  function handleSliderClick() {
var selected_slider = $(this).closest(".vas-slider").attr('id');
var sliderHandle = $("#" + selected_slider).find('.noUi-base .noUi-handle');
$(sliderHandle).show();
  }
});
```

I made a JSFiddle so you can see what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/nf34ymty/2/

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the slider's event to listen for the change instead of capturing only the `click` event:

```
slider.noUiSlider.on('change', function(){
    $(slider.querySelector('.noUi-handle')).show();  
});
```

Override the animation CSS:

```
.noUi-state-tap .noUi-connect,
.noUi-state-tap .noUi-origin {
-webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/nf34ymty/3/).